# Maximum Google Drive Revisions ID?

Tags: javascript, drive

Does anyone know what the max revision ID is for a google docs file on google drive?

You can retrieve the revision ID via DriveApp.Revisions.lists[#].items.id. It is a numerical value that increases with each revision. I was wondering what the maximum ID is because i would like to use the revision ID to track the state of a document i am editing.

Comment: what makes you think there's a maximum? Why can't a document be edited as many times as you like? I'd guess that, unless it's explicitly documented somewhere, the maximum is probably just the maximum value of whatever numeric data type the revision ID is. I can't see why they'd put a lower limit on it, really. Also according to the API, the revision ID is a string, not a number, so if it's actually some sort of GUID then there's probably no hard limit imposed by the program.

Comment: The docs don't say if the ID is autoincremented relative to the parent file, or relative to a user or a random value. It is shown as a "string" value type. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions#resource